# Powershell Copying file from a mapped drive "Z:" to users local "C:"

Tags: windows, powershell, openvpn, silent-installer

Hello I want my powershell script to be able to copy a file from a mapped drive (Z:) and copy it to the user in the domains "C:/temp/" folder. Currently, my script looks like this.

```
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Computer Name you are accessing'


########## Install Software On PC ##########

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "\\$Computer\c$\temp\openVPN"

    Copy-Item "Z:\(15) IT\VPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win7.exe" "\\$Computer\c$\temp\" -Recurse
    Copy-Item "Z:\(15) IT\VPN\office.opvn" "\\$Computer\c$\temp\" -Recurse


    Write-Host "Installing openVPN on $Computer"

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "c:\temp\openVPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win7.exe" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait} 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "c:\temp\openVPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win7.exe" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait}
```

However, I receive the error

**Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Z' does not exist.**

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You could try using the absolute path of the mapped drive (\\servername\path\) instead of the drive letter(Z)

Comment: so like "Copy-Item "\\$Computer\z$\(15) IT\VPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win7.exe" "\\$Computer\c$\temp\" -Recurse" ? I tried that an still get the same issue @Dexirian

Comment: If Z is reffering to a drive mapped on a different computer, I think you would to specify the entire path of the mapped drive instead of Z$. My Z is currently mapped to \\server.domain.x\support\devops\tools
So I would invoke Copy-Item -Source "\\server.domain.x\support\devops\tools\filename" -Destination "\\$Computer\c$\temp\"

Comment: Yes I did that but let me double check with you if I did it correctly. I go to command prompt and type in "net use Z:" and that give me remote name of "\\***.**.*.**\FileStorage". so ..    "Copy-Item "\\***.**.*.**\FileStorage\(15) IT\VPN\openvpn-install-2.4.8-I602-Win7.exe" "\\$Computer\c$\temp\" -Recurse" ? Still receive same error. @Dexirian

Comment: Are you running the script with your user ? If you see the drive and are not running on an elevated prompt, then your script should see the drive. If you run using a different user (eg: Running through a service account as a scheduled task) or as an administrator, it ,is likely not mapped for that user.(Whether it's "admin mode" or another user, you might need to map the drive through that user also : Reference for Run As Administrator issue : https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co

Comment: I'm just trying to run the script on my own account and I have the Z: mapped @SagePourpre

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, your session is not seeing the Z drive.

Disconnect the Z drive if you can.  Then map the drive in the same session using New-PSDrive PowerShell command, before accessing the Z drive.

```
New-PSDrive –Name "Z" –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\servername\path" –Persist
```

Also, try to run PowerShell in both standard mode and 'Run As Admin' mode.

Comment: Strange but I did that and now it is working! Thanks!

Comment: Great.  Happy to help you.

Comment: It works, thanks! But I am not able to see mapped drive through above command in "This PC".